# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState on screen orientation changed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm stuck with this problem. I'm switching fragments with swipe.

on swipe left:

```
public void nextFragment() {
    if(collection.iterator(). hasNext()){
        String fragmentNameToHide = collection.iterator().current();
        String fragmentNameToShow = collection.iterator().next();
        Fragment fragmentToShow = null;
        if((fragmentToShow=fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentNameToShow))==null){
            Class<?> className=null;
            try {
                className = Class.forName(fragmentNameToShow);
                Constructor<?> constructor = className.getConstructor();
                Object object = constructor.newInstance();
                fragmentToShow = (Fragment) object;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_right, R.animator.slide_out_left);
        Fragment fragmentToHide = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentNameToHide);
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentToShow, fragmentNameToShow);
        ft.show(fragmentToShow);
        ft.hide(fragmentToHide);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    }
}
```

on swipe right:

```
public boolean prevFragment() {
    if(collection.iterator().isLast()){
        Log.i("prv", "son");
        String fragmentNameToRemove = collection.iterator().current();
        String fragmentNameToShow = collection.getFragmentList().get(0);
        Fragment fragmentToShow = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentNameToShow);
        Fragment fragmentToRemove2 = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(collection.getFragmentList().get(1));
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_out_right);
        Fragment fragmentToRemove = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentNameToRemove);
        ft.hide(fragmentToRemove);
        ft.hide(fragmentToRemove2);
        ft.show(fragmentToShow);
        ft.commit();
        collection.iterator().setPosition(0);
        Delict.getInstance().releaseDelict();

        return false;
    }else{
        Log.i("prv", "son değil");
        if (collection.iterator().hasPrev()) {
            String fragmentNameToRemove = collection.iterator().current();
            String fragmentNameToShow = collection.iterator().prev();
            Fragment fragmentToShow = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentNameToShow);
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_out_right);
            Fragment fragmentToRemove = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentNameToRemove);
            ft.show(fragmentToShow);
            ft.hide(fragmentToRemove);
            ft.commit();
            return true;
        }else{
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my codes:
My main activity:

```
public class DelictActivity extends Activity implements SimpleGestureListener {
private SimpleGestureFilter detector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_delict);
    detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this, getFragmentManager());
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Fragment fragment = null;
        FragmentTransaction ft =  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if((fragment=getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("com.example.PlateFragment"))==null){
            PlateFragment plate = new PlateFragment();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, plate, "com.example.PlateFragment");
            ft.show(plate);
        }else{
            ft.show(fragment);
        }
        ft.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
   this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
}
```

}

My frist fragment:

```
public class PlateFragment extends Fragment {
public PlateFragment() {
}
Button enterPlate;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plate, null);

    enterPlate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.openPlateLayer);
    enterPlate.setOnClickListener(openPlateLayerListener);
    return view;
}

OnClickListener openPlateLayerListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        PlateDialogFragment newFragment = PlateDialogFragment.newInstance();
        newFragment.addListener(dialogFragmentListener);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"dialog");

    }
};
DialogFragmentListener dialogFragmentListener = new DialogFragmentListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        Delict delict =Delict.getInstance();
        enterPlate.setText(delict.getPlate());
    }
};
```

}

My second fragment:

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {
public CategoryFragment() {
}
TextView text;
View view;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, null);
    Button categoryLayerButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.selectCategory);
    categoryLayerButton.setOnClickListener(categoryLayerButtonListener);
    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
    return view;
}
OnClickListener categoryLayerButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CategoryDialogFragment newFragment = CategoryDialogFragment.newInstance();
        newFragment.addListener(dialogFragmentListener);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"dialog");

    }
};

DialogFragmentListener dialogFragmentListener = new DialogFragmentListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        Delict delict = Delict.getInstance();
        if(delict.getCategoryList().size()>1){
            text.setText("ihlallerini yaptı;");
        }else if(delict.getCategoryList().size()==1){
            text.setText("ihlalini yaptı;");
        }

        loadCategoryImages();
    }
};

private void loadCategoryImages() {
    view.findViewById(R.id.selectCategory).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    LinearLayout stack = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.categoryLayout);
    Delict delict = Delict.getInstance();

    for(int i = 0; i<delict.getCategoryList().size(); i++){
        ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins((-30*i), 0, 0, 0);
        image.setLayoutParams(params);
        stack.addView(image);
    }

}


private static final String FRAGMENT_KEY = "fragmentkey";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean(FRAGMENT_KEY, true);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if(savedInstanceState.getBoolean(FRAGMENT_KEY)){
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment frag1 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("com.example.PlateFragment");
            ft.hide(frag1);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

    }
}
```

}

LogCat says:

```
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1265)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1276)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:541)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:525)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at com.example.fragmentmanager.FragmentCollection.prevFragment(FragmentCollection.java:77)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at com.example.SimpleGestureFilter.onFling(SimpleGestureFilter.java:130)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:579)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at com.example.SimpleGestureFilter.onTouchEvent(SimpleGestureFilter.java:53)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at com.example.activities.DelictActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(DelictActivity.java:45)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1897)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5726)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2922)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2498)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:864)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2507)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4447)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-13 15:01:43.320: E/AndroidRuntime(8477):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And third fragment is something like that. As you can see, on `onCreate` method in the activity, first fragment is added to the container. I have 2 xml for main activity. First one is for portrait mode the other one is for landscape mode. On screen orientation changed if orientation is portrait, one of these fragment will be on screen. If orientation is landscape, there should be always same layout- the layout which is for landscape mode for activity.

But while swiping after screen orientation change on second activity, i get this error. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you define your activity on the manifest file like this ? If you didn't because of recreating the activty it could take such type of error.

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"